# Why is there a philosophy tag if philosophical questions are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, scope

The OP for [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83653/platos-cave-allegory-how-to-respond-to-the-argument-in-favor-of-ignorance) queried that it was closed due to the following reason :

> General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer. See: On-topic and constructive examples.

They argued that since there was a 'philosophy' tag they had asked the question in sincerity :

> If the "Philosophy" and "Evangelism" tags were not on this forum, I would not have posted. My concern is sincere.

This comment was answered by a Moderator but I wondered if a more full explanation might be helpful in this instance.

Answer (score 6):

**General** philosophy questions aren't on topic here. **Historical** or **theological** philosophy questions can be. Here are some examples:

- [What influence did Greek philosophy have on the formation of orthodox Christian doctrine?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/68335/6071)
- [What influence did Greco-Roman philosophy have on the doctrine of "creatio ex nihilo"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/59363/6071)
- [What is the relation between the Logos of Greek Philosophy and the Logos in Christianity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/55244/6071)
- [According to Reformed Theology, how is Compatibilism different than Hard Determinism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/59412/6071)
- [In Aquinas's first proof of God's existence, what is the difference between accidentally and essentially ordered causal series?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/34618/6071)
- [Are there any accidents (philosophical term) in God?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/13965/6071)
- [What positions with regard to epistemology exist in Catholicism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/50756/6071)
- [How can Protestants authoritatively declare something wrong or heretical under Sola Scriptura?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/68346/6071)

The last one is maybe a bit of a stretch, but it concerns epistemology, which is definitely a part of philosophy. We probably need some more epistemology questions actually!

Answer (score 3):

We have [sex](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) but you can't ask about Kama Sutra here either!

But this is a good question that I would like the community to help us moderators with, because I don't know what the difference between philosophy an apologetics is when it comes to this site. We've said for a long time that apologetics is on topic, but always said "general philosophical question" and I don't know how much more general philosophy you can get from something that is taught in every philosophy 101 class.

There is another site to ask [site:philosophy.se] questions, we don't often migrate there though, you're not apt to get a Christian answer either.

But in general, the tag is a noun describing the question.  If the tag were anything else it would be a meta-tag.  If you tag [philosophy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy) you don't make the question a philosophy question, you make the question about philosophy in general. Similarly you don't make the question an evangelism question, you make the question about evangelism.  "How do I evangelize in this particular case" is not a question *about* spreading the Gospel it is a question about how to spread the Gospel.

---

Furthermore, I've always thought that question about distinctly Christian philosophies (like the Natural Moral Law) were on topic as long as they were Thomistic, not just Aristotelian, I've gotten a moderate amount of pushback on that view and had some questions closed when they weren't clearly on the subject of Christianity, I appreciate that and won't try to foist it on the community just because I'm a mod and a Catholic. I don't really know if there is an Evangelical or Reformed philosophy outside of the Bible, I suspect not.

Comment: I strongly believe it's a chapter of church history on why evangelicals (esp. in the first half of 20th century) are "allergic" to using philosophy in doing their theology for fear of allowing Hellenistic concepts to creep in, etc.  Reacting to scholasticism (in Luther's time) and to Enlightenment (in more recent time) are 2 big factors.  In contrast, evangelical scholarship in recent decades has shown fruitful engagement with philosophy coinciding with the proliferation of study of how C.S. Lewis used philosophy for apologetics & theology.  But this has not penetrated the general public yet.

Comment: I know it when I see it.  Does that suffice? 